# Cannot change video mute property using Javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I have a video layer:

```
...
<body>
<a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'http://www.youtube.com /watch?v=xNUGS3NiQIw',containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:1, opacity:1}">background</a>
...
```

And I'd like to change video mute property to false whenever a button is cliked so I use this:

```
...
 <a href="#" OnClick='$("bgndVideo").data("mute","true");'>Turn volume on</a>
...
```

but nothing happens... what am i doing wrong? Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<a href="#" OnClick='$("#bgndVideo").data("mute","true");'>Turn volume on</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's functions for it: $.fn.toggleVolume() , $.fn.muteYTPVolume(), $.fn.unmuteYTPVolume()

```
<a href="#"  onclick="$('#bgndVideo').toggleVolume()">mute/unmute</a>
```